# Filtering the AD group

Tags: powershell

I used the below code for pulling out AD group of users

```
$users = Get-Content u:\users.txt
ForEach ($User in $users) {
$user1 = Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties *;
$GroupMembership = ($user1.memberof | % { (Get-ADGroup $_).Name; }) -join ';';
$User1.SamAccountName + ';' + $GroupMembership >>test4.csv
}
```

I would like to add a filter which fetches the only particular type of ad group say starting with `SG`

I had tried putting a filter but it gave me a boolean true or false but not the filtered value.

Answer (score 0):

You want to filter the `Name` property starting with `SG`?, try this:

```
Get-ADGroup -filter 'Name -like "SG*"'
```

Comment: I am aware of the above condition, I was trying to integrate the same in the function which i am unable to

Comment: Im not sure what your output should look like. Can you provide a sample output of `$user1.memberof` and how you want `GroupMembership to look like?

Comment: below is the result set that i got on running the code that i posted:                   
"username"
SG-****
DL-**
DL-***                                                                                                          i dont want the AD groups starting with DL i want only the ones starting with SG in the final output file. @MartinBrandl

Comment: $user1.memberof gives me a list of AD group eg CN=SG-*******,CN=DL-***** and other attributes which i am not bothered